# How to adjust container in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I ajdust container to make it full width? [image]

This is the space that's container taking right now, but I want it to have full width (like website).

I have created it like this

```
<div class="container-fluid container-va">
        <div class="row row-dk">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>SOME TEXT</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
   </div>
```

I have tried adjusting css like:

```
.container-va {
width: 100%;
}
```

but it doesn't work... Help please!

Comment: Use .container-fluid for a full width container,
spanning the entire width of your viewport.
<div class= "container-fluid" >
...
</div>

Comment: check the parent div's width of container-va

Comment: I'm using container-fluid

Comment: .container { width: 100%; } try this

Comment: .container-va {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}

Comment: I don't think you need a container if you want it to always be full width. Try removing the outer `div` with the `container-fluid` class.